# Why laradock use one database for different project?

Tags: database, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laradock

I use standart laradock https://laradock.io/

And I have two project in different folders.

```
E:\laravel\smskin\blog\laradock
```

And

```
E:\laravel\JSONAPI\blog\laradock
```

I can start every project, and is realy different projects:

```
docker-compose up -d nginx mysql workspace phpmyadmin  php-worker
```

But, why is projects use one database?
Identical tables, changes in one project database are reflected in another. I want to use different databases for different projects. Where does the larodok store the data?

Comment: Maybe your .env settings point to the same database?

Comment: blog/laradock/.env DATA_PATH_HOST=~/.laradock/data

Comment: I mean: is the contents of the .env file equal in both cases? If so, you point to the same database of course. Check the `DB_*` settings.

Comment: Yes. .laradock/.end equal.   And METABASE_DB_FILE=metabase.db

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 projects. Both projects have their own `.env` file. But in your case the settings in both these files are equal. Hence, both projects share 1 database.

Change the settings in one of the `.env` files to match a different database.

Comment: Where can I change these settings?